# Можно ли задать страницы для исполнения Chrome Extension в его настройках?

Tags: google-chrome, chrome-extension

Пишу расширение для Хрома.
Мне нужно, чтобы оно запускалось на определенных страницах.
Можно было бы прописать список адресов в `manifest.json`:

```
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["http://myUrl1.com/*"],
    ...
}]
```

Однако расширение предназначено для работы с определенной системой, но вот где она будет находиться, заранее неизвестно.

Есть вариант - прописать запуск на всех адресах:

```
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ],
    ...
}]
```

а запускать нужные функции, сравнивая адрес текущей страницы с записанными в параметрах. Но при этом расширение все равно будет отрабатывать на всех страницах, как минимум, функция проверки и сравнения адреса.

Собственно вопрос: можно ли задавать список адресов (например, в параметрах расширения) и как-то применять его на лету? Я так понимаю, манифест на лету модифицировать нельзя.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Существует возможность выполнять content-script не только через директиву в *manifest*, но так же и "программно", через background-скрипт.

Для этого в манифесте необходимо указать:

```
"permissions": [
  ...
  "http://*/*"
  "https://*/*"
],
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
},
...
```

При этом вам не требуется указывать директиву "content_script".

В **background.js** вы отслеживаете открытие новых вкладок или изменения URL у текущих, например, с помощью событий ([события chrome.tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#events)).

Это выглядит приблизительно вот так:

```
const ALLOWED_URL = '...'; // Разрешенный URL

// отслеживаем изменение во вкладках
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo) {
  if(changeInfo.status === 'completed' && changeInfo.url === ALLOWED_URL) {

    // запускаем content-script
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
      file: 'content-script.js'
    });
  }
});
```